# Getting ClassNotFound for PaxExam Option class when running test

Tags: java, osgi, classpath, pax-exam

When running unit tests with PaxExam I'm getting this ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2894)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2903)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1607)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.findAndInvoke(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:94)
at org.ops4j.pax.exam.invoker.junit.internal.JUnitProbeInvoker.call(JUnitProbeInvoker.java:73)
at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.RemoteFrameworkImpl.invokeMethodOnService(RemoteFrameworkImpl.java:433)
at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.framework.RemoteFrameworkImpl.invokeMethodOnService(RemoteFrameworkImpl.java:406)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:178)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:174)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:557)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:812)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:671)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This happens even though the PaxExam JAR (and all dependencies) are on the Maven classpath.

I have been trying to hunt down a solution to this problem for quite some time; I would really appreciate any advice anyone can give. Thanks.

EDIT:

The error seems to arise from the fact that each test is implementing a interface `BundleTest` imported (dynamically) from another bundle that provides a default `@Configuration` method. This bundle does not (currently) explicitly export or import the pax exam classes, so that might be part of the problem?

I will update the question again once I have tested it to find out.

Comment: some more details about your test setup could be helpful here

Comment: see OP for update; the test setup includes a default implementation of the @Configuration method provided via an interface default method. That's the only thing I can think of worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem indeed seemed to be that the class was referencing via import another class that imported Pax classes.

To illustrate the imports:

class A <-- class B <-- Pax

The problem was that class B was not importing the Pax Exam classes in the Bundle manifest. So while Pax was creating the dynamic imports for the test classes in class A, class B was from another bundle. That meant OSGi wasn't resolving the imports in class B.

The lesson then, I suppose, is *check the declared dependencies of your other dependent bundles*.

Hopefully this helps someone else who has this problem in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle needs to import the package `org.ops4j.pax.exam`, e.g. something like this in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Import-Package: org.ops4j.pax.exam
```

Update: see [this wiki page](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Why_does_my_bundle_throw_ClassNotFoundException_or_NoClassDefFoundError%3F) for further information.

Comment: But the whole point of Pax is that it's supposed to _create_ a bundle from your tests on the fly and dynamically import stuff. Why would I need to import that package?

Comment: I think it's just a weird classpath issue. Once things get into the OSGi environment, all hell breaks loose with that stuff :(

Comment: Err there's no such thing as a "classpath".

Comment: Do you mean in OSGi? There technically is.... it's just sort of masked by the package import/export system.

Comment: There is a classpath within bundles only. Package imports and exports don't mask the global classpath, they replace it. So it's not a helpful concept.

Comment: Perhaps. But OSGi implementations use internal ClassLoaders.... even if the model they follow is very different. But that's the point. It can be very hard to understand how they are discovering classes.

Comment: How it is hard?? Just look at the imports. Traditional Java with its flat classpath is harder... Anyway this discussion is not really getting us anywhere.

Comment: I explained what I think the problem was in my own answer. I'm giving you +1 though for having an answer that was _technically_ correct!